# xmpp protocol decentralized actual meaning?

Tags: xmpp

I just started working on xmpp its wiki page says that "The architecture of the XMPP network is similar to email; anyone can run their own XMPP server and there is no central master server."Hence it is decentralized

In my application I want that user can create a specific group chat box on a click of button.
My question is if the main user who created chatbox become offline will the chat box created by him will remain alive as decentralized suggest that user who created will act as a server. If not , could anyone suggest what can be done for keeping chatboxes alive even when the user become offline.

Comment: The title of your post does not really reflect the content of your question.

Comment: @flow is it alright now? sorry for inconvenience.

Comment: I still can't infer what your question is about by reading the title, which is usually a sign of a bad title. :( Please try to be more precise with your title so that other users can benefit from your question too. I think you want to ask something like "Are XMPP conference chats permanent or will they be destroyed when the initial users leaves?"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Multi User Chats (called 'MUC' in the XMPP world) are hosted by a XMPP component. This means that the user who initiated the chat **does not* act as chat provider, but this particular MUC component. This component runs usually on the same machine as your XMPP server. Therefore the chat exists - if the MUC is marked as permanent - even if the user quits the chat.

More information can be found in [XEP-0045: Multi-User Chat](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0045.html)

Comment: thanks for your reply ... could you point me to some source which help me writing xmpp client for android app from scratch ...not able to find anything solid till now

Comment: There are a dozen open source Android XMPP clients out there. Study their source, this should get you a good starting point.